# Registering to 'GCAllocationTick_V1' CLR event from C#

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection, clr, clr4.0

I'm trying to add some profiling capabilities to a server application.
I have found 'GCAllocationTick_V1' event and I would like to monitor it and react to it in code. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any information regarding this topic.

Actually, I found out that my production server sometimes allocates ~1GC/Sec, which causes the GC to go nuts. I couldn't find any pattern to this behaviour and it never happened on my DEV ENV. Thus, I'm searching for a way to catch the memory allocation LIVE.
Be my guests and offer any other ideas on how to find the source to the problem.

Thanks,

O

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the EventLogWatcher class?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogwatcher(v=vs.90).aspx

(From [C# - Subscribing to a ETW event channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391893/c-sharp-subscribing-to-a-etw-event-channel))

An example found here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danielvl/archive/2009/02/02/how-to-consume-etw-events-from-c.aspx